# Exponential Distribution - the average lifetime

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, exponential-distribution

I have an exponential distribution modelling the lifetime of certain product:

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}\lambda e^{-\lambda x} &,\text{ if }  x\geq 0\\0 &, \text{ if } x  <  0\end{array}\right.$$

A text has the following statement: In this case, **$\lambda$ is the average lifetime** and $x$ is a failure time.

I'd like to know why the average lifetime is not the expected value, ie, $1/\lambda$.

Thank you.

Comment: As you have written it, $\lambda$ is the failure rate and $1/\lambda$ is the average lifetime.

Comment: I imagine that there was a little typo on text. Many thanks!